# Changing the user Selected Color in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angular

How Can I change  the dynamically selected color using function in Javascript and change the color and give opacity in AngularJS.

Basically I have a field with color picker in my form where the user can select his own color and we need to pass the color dynamically in function and change the colorby giving it some opacity.

This is my requirement.I am building the application in Angular JS.I am a beginner in Angular Js.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question correctly  it will be helpful to you

```js
 var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
    app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){

    });
```

```css
.red{
background-color:red;
}
.green{
background-color:green;
}
.yellow{
background-color:yellow;
}
.blue{
background-color:blue;
}

div{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    color:<select ng-model="color_pic">
        <option value="red" >red</option>
        <option value="green">green</option>
        <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>    
    </select>
    opacity  (0.0 to 1.0):<input type="text"  ng-model="div_opacity">
    <div ng-class="color_pic" style="opacity:{{div_opacity}}">
    </div>
    
</body>
```